# How many bit strings of length eight start with a 1 bit and end with the two bits 00?

Tags: combinatorics

since we can choose the first spot and the last two spots in one way so we have 2^5 for the others 
Is that right?

Comment: Yup, that's right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Break the question down into parts, it always helps me to understand the problem:

*How many bit strings of length **8***

So we have 8 places to be filled that can either be 1 or 0 (binary)

$ \_ $ $ \_ $ $ \_ $ $ \_ $ $ \_ $ $ \_ $ $ \_ $ $ \_ $

*start with a **1** bit and end with two bits **00***

These are fixed values and take up the following positions:

$ 1$ $ \_ $ $ \_ $ $ \_ $ $ \_ $ $ \_ $ $ 0 $ $ 0 $

There are 5 remaining positions that can be filled by either a 1 or 0.

Since we have **2** choices for each of the remaining **5** tasks, and repeat elements are aloud (11,00) we can use permutations formula:

$$n^r$$

Where $n$ is the number of possible choices to for each task and $r$ is the  number of tasks.

$$\therefore n^r = 2^5 = 32 $$

---

In short, yes your answer would be correct, I just wanted to break the problem down for you.